# can't convert pytorch tensor dtype from float64 to double

Tags: python, pytorch

I need to convert an int to a double tensor, and I've already tried several ways including `torch.tensor([x], dtype=torch.double)`, first defining the tensor and then converting the dtype to double with `x_tensor.double()`, and also defining the tensor with `torch.DoubleTensor([x])` but none actually change the dtype from `torch.float64`. Here's the code snippet

```
>>> x = 6
>>> x = torch.tensor([x], dtype=torch.double)
>>> x
tensor([6.], dtype=torch.float64)

>>> x = 6
>>> x_tensor = torch.Tensor([x])
>>> x_double = x_tensor.double()
>>> x_double
tensor([6.], dtype=torch.float64)

>>> x_tensor = torch.DoubleTensor([x])
>>> x_tensor
tensor([6.], dtype=torch.float64)
```

Any ideas as to why it's not converting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is converting; `torch.float64` and `torch.double` are the [same thing](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html)